# Dynamic Parameter showing too many values

Tags: sql-server, join, crystal-reports

I am currently creating a simple report in Crystal Reports with two tables:

```
{Table1.group_name_id} --> {Table2.technical_group_id}

Table 1 holds all of the groups; ID's, Names etc
Table 2 holds only the technical groups ID
```

With these two tables linked it means the only records that will return are those where technical groups are involved, perfect! But now I want to add a dynamic parameter to return the Technical Group Names for the End User to select.

Because `{Table2}` only holds one field (the ID) which links to `{Table1}`'s ID, I have to perform the Parameter selection on `{Table1}`'s name field.

But this is pulling back all of `{Table1}`'s names and is discounting the Join on {Table2} even with an enforced join present.

Is there a way to force it to only pull back `{Table1}`'s names as long as it matches the JOIN between `{Table1} and {Table2}`?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit (additional information)**

[image: Table Link]

Comment: which join have you used?

Comment: It's an INNER JOIN - which should only return those groups which are present in both tables, but returns all from {Table1} for some reason.

Comment: Inner join shouldn't work that way... check data if you are getting full data then it means all records are getting matched

Comment: I've ran the INNER JOIN on the database directly and only 63 records get returned. But doing it through Crystal it's like it ignores the JOIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I thought - the problem was Crystal Reports was not recognising the JOIN when displaying the parameter values.

After some reading, I found out that the JOINS are only recognised when the query is passed to the database (logically). So when selecting a Parameter, it doesn't recognise the JOINS.

I got around this by creating a custom SQL command, forcing it to only pull back the groups in the second table.

Answer (score 0):

First, please confirm your join INNER JOIN.

[image]

For Addition,
You can pass the User Input as a parameter in to the crystal report and use this {@Parameter} to filter the result set using SelectionFormula in Crystal Report.

Or you can even set the selectionformula itself from the application.

Comment: That's what I'm having to resort to now, but I am looking for a Dynamic Parameter as opposed to a Static one.

Comment: Once you created a Parameter Variable in Crystal Report , then you can pass the run time value / dynamic value to theat Parameter in crystal report from your application. If you use the filter ( tablefieldname = @parametername) in your SelectionFormula , then it fill works as a WHERE clause in Sql.

Comment: Sorry just to make sure I'm clear.... This is what I had done:

1. Create the JOIN between the two tables as described above
2. Create a Dynamic Parameter on `{table1}.group_name` 
3. Create a Selection Expert formula on `{table1}.group_name` = {?Parameter}

But this still shows all of the customer names from `{table1}` and not only those with the same ID as `{table2}`

Comment: Then please check your join , it should be INNER JOIN.

Comment: Can u please share the screenshot your join and table data?

Comment: Just added the screenshot - If I make the dynamic parameter based on `{tps_support_group}.tps_guid` I get the correct number (63) of entries. 

If I do it on `{tps_group}.title` I get hundreds

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109249/discussion-between-abdul-rasheed-and-omisnomis).

Comment: can u please change the **enforced both** to **not enforced** and check